# cssText or individual stylename?

Tags: javascript, css, optimization, repaint, reflow

When we are applying **a lot of** style changes using JavaScript to a single element, [phpied](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/) & [Writing Efficient JavaScript](http://www.slideshare.net/nzakas/writing-efficient-javascript) (slide 87) suggests:

> instead of applying styles one by one using style.stylename, apply everything in one go using cssText or changing classname as it'll reduce reflows/repaints

Which is better when there's only a **single** style change?

```
document.getElementById('myid').style.cssText += ";color:#999;";
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('myid').style.color = "#999";
```

[jsperf.com/csstext-vs-styles-single](http://jsperf.com/csstext-vs-styles-single) shows that when there's only a single style change, using individual style name is faster than cssText.

Are there any other factors also to be considered?

Comment: @Gaby: which one do you suggest? individual stylename or cssText?

Comment: individual stylename .. since you deal with just one property..

Comment: @Gaby: When there's only 1 style change, is the no. of reflows same in both cases?

Comment: One nice thing about cssText is you don't have to camelCase properties like borderBottomColor or fontSize.

Comment: @Anish, yes.. just one reflow..

Comment: document.getElementById('myid').style = 'color:#999'; works too, so I can't find any difference between them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use the individual stylename in your case, because you are going to change only one style.
 :)

Comment: When there's only 1 style change, will the no. of reflows be same in both cases?