# DOM how to add more than one style in a div

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to add more than one style attribute using DOM `setAttribute`, but it doesn't work. How can I do it using JavaScript?

```
 var modificar = document.getElementById('opciones');
 modificar.setAttribute('style','float:left');
 modificar.setAttribute('style','margin:0px');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setAttribute` is most likely working OK, but since you are invoking it twice, the result of the first call gets overridden by the second one.

Either do:

```
modificar.setAttribute('style','float: left; margin:0px;');
```

Or use the `style` attribute as suggested in another answer.

Comment: you mean cssText instead of style?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254412/csstext-or-individual-stylename and http://philarcher.org/diary/2012/csstext/

Comment: @karaxuna I think these are two different things: using `element.setAttribute()` with the `style` attribute, which directly changes the property, or going throught the `element.style` abstraction, which then requires you to do `element.style.cssText` in order to change everything in one go.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`style` object](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-style) on the element:

```
modificar.style.cssFloat = "left";
modificar.style.margin = "0px";
```

(Note that it's `cssFloat`, not `float`, from JavaScript. That's because `float` was a "future reserved word" in the ECMAScript specification 3rd edition [it no longer is in ES5], and you can't use reserved words when writing a property name in literal notation. So when defining the style object, they chose names like `cssFloat` when there was a conflict.)

For properties with dashes in them, you use camelCase instead:

```
modificar.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
```

Comment: I think it should be like this: modificar.style.cssFloat = "left";

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it:

```
modificar.style.setAttribute('float','left');
modificar.style.setAttribute('margin','0px');
```

or:

```
modificar.style.cssFloat  = 'left';
modificar.style.margin = '0px';
```

(edit: corrected to `cssFloat` in accordance with later posts)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the class to the div like:

```
var modificar = document.getElementById('opciones');
x.className = "someClass";
```

and in the CSS, add as many style as you want like:

```
.someClass {
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    color : red;
    ...
    ...
}
```