# Chrome: Why change style in batch(cssText) is slower then change in single(.style.property) way?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, performance-testing

In `High Performance Javascript` book, I read about for minimizing repaints and reflows, batch DOM changes could lead a better performance, like using:

```
var el = document.getElementById('mydiv');
el.style.cssText = 'border-left: 1px; border-right: 2px; padding: 5px;';
```

instead of

```
var el = document.getElementById('mydiv');
el.style.borderLeft = '1px';
el.style.borderRight = '2px';
el.style.padding = '5px';
```

I did a test in Chrome, but the result is opposite, here is my test code:

```
var ie = (function(){
    var undef, v = 3, div = document.createElement('div');

    while (
        div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE '+(++v)+']><i></i><![endif]-->',
        div.getElementsByTagName('i')[0]
    );

    return v> 4 ? v : undef;
}());


// First insert 100*100 element

var total = 100 * 100;
var round = 100 * 100;

var body = document.querySelector("body");

if (ie) {
    total = round = 100 * 10;       
}

var createElement = function (id) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("id", "id-" + id);
    return div;
}

for (var i = 0; i <= total; i++) {
    body.appendChild(createElement(i));
}

// Then change style in random
function randomFromInterval(from, to) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to-from+1)+from);
}

function randomWidth() {
    return randomFromInterval(0, 200) + "px";
}

function randomHeight() {
    return randomFromInterval(0, 200) + "px";
}

function randomColor() {
    var r = randomFromInterval(0, 255),
        g = randomFromInterval(0, 255),
        b = randomFromInterval(0, 255);

    return "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
}

var time = +new Date();

for (var i = 0; i <= round; i++) {
    var id = randomFromInterval(0, total);
    var div = document.querySelector("#id-" + id);

    // The `slower` way...but it is faster, use less time
    div.style.width = randomHeight();
    div.style.height = randomWidth();
    div.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();

    // var text = "width: " + randomWidth() + "; height: " + randomHeight() + "; background: " + randomColor() + ";"
    // div.style.cssText = text;
}

console.log(+new Date() - time);
```

Here is my demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/9BV5E/

http://jsfiddle.net/9BV5E/1/

the first one I using `.style.` way, and the second one is using `cssTest` way;

And I also test them in IE8, the two way's time are almost the same.

So is the book wrong? Or there are other reasons?

Answer (score 2):

May I ask how you are testing this?

Have you entered the test cases into, say [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/) a la [these](http://jsperf.com/csstext-vs-individual-styles-3)?

The information available roundly indicates [cssText is better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254412/csstext-or-individual-stylename) [when setting multiple styles](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/) vs [individual ones](http://www.slideshare.net/nzakas/writing-efficient-javascript), when performing tests I cant seem to replicate the results you've noted.